# Reinject NF_STOLEN SYN packet into the stack

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel, kernel-module, netfilter

I am working with a transparent proxy implemented in kernel space (4.9.0-14-amd64).
The proxy needs to implement some kind of fate-sharing, which means that client's TCP connect() will return only after Proxy-Server TCP connection is established.

Consider a simple Client --- Proxy --- Server topology.
Here is the concept that I want to achieve:

1. Client initiates TCP connect toward the server.
2. Proxy intercepts the SYN packet using a netfilter hook, stores the skb, initiates a queue_work to connect to server, and returns NF_STOLEN.

When Proxy is connected to the server, it needs to somehow reinject the SYN packet into the stack, so that Proxy stack can continue with the SYN/ACK and Proxy TCP accept() can be returned.

Is it possible to achieve this using `dev_queue_xmit()`, `ip_local_deliver()`, or `netif_rx()`, etc. without passing again through the netfilter hook?
I know that SYNPROXY implementation handles this case, but the module sends its own SYN/ACK packet. In my case, the same SYN packet needs to be reinjected in the stack, and forwarded to upper layers, so that it can reach the local listening socket of the Proxy.

EDIT: I tried to use `netif_rx()` after copied skb using `skb_copy()`, but after calling `netif_rx()` Netfilter PREROUTING hook is called again. I want to reinject the skb just right after where it was hooked, so that it can continue to the next iptables filter (TPROXY).

EDIT 2: I changed the priority of netfilter hook so that it will be called after all PREROUTING iptables. Somehow, I want to call:

```
NF_HOOK(NFPROTO_IPV4, NF_INET_LOCAL_IN, &init_net, NULL,
copy_skb, copy_skb->dev, NULL, ip_rcv_finish);
```

but this is not possible, as `ip_rcv_finish()` is declared static inside ip_input.c.